# attach new property to specific location within object

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I attach an additional property to an object, does it have to go at the end, or can I put it at a specified position.

```
function reassign(obj){
  delete obj.c;
  obj.c = "new three";

  var t = "<table border=\"1\">";
  for (var i in obj){
    t += "<tr><td>" + obj[i] + "</td></tr>"; 
  }
  t += "</table>";
  return t;
}

var obj = {
  a : "one",
  b : "two",
  c : "three",
  d : "four" 
};

var reassigned = reassign(obj);
document.write(reassigned);
```

Would it be possible somehow to put the new `obj.c` in the third position again after it's been deleted, rather than having it appended to the end? Of course I could skip the delete part. But even without that, I could also for example intend inject `alphabeta: "one point five"` into the second position. Is it possible? Thanks!

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/otudew/2/edit)

Comment: 4.3.3 Object  
An object is a member of the type Object. It is an **unordered collection of properties** each of which contains a primitive value, object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is called a method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array elements are ordered; object properties are not. You should never assume that object properties will be iterated in a particular order.

If order is important to you, create a new `order:[]` property which contains an array of property names, and you can iterate through that:

```
var obj = {
  a : "one",
  b : "two",
  c : "three",
  d : "four",
  order : ['a','b','c','d']
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a cool idea. Can you show me a bit how you'd implement it?

Comment: I thought I just did. If it's actual code you're looking for, just [read the documentation on array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods) and apply one to your specific needs. [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) in particular is able to insert arbitrary numbers of elements into the middle of an array.

Comment: Okay, but why would I want to splice the array. Wouldn't that always need to be the same?

Comment: If you want to put a new property in the object in a particular spot in the order, then you need to splice (or push or unshift) it into the `order` array. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, so I'm just handing you suggestions. By all means, research the methods and do what's best for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

*Objects* are unordered. You can either create an *Array* and break your object into Key-Value pairs or you can use an array to index object keys.

**Option 1**

```
var collection = [
  {key1: value1},
  {key2: value2},
  {key3: value3}
];
```

**Option 2**

```
var obj = {
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2,
  key3: value3
};

// you can index just the values
var index_to_value = [
  obj['key1'],
  obj['key2'],
  obj['key3']
];

// or you can index by key, if necessary
var index_to_key = [
  'key1', 'key2', 'key3'
];
```

And of course, if it doesn't interfere, you can put the index in the object:

```
var obj = {
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2,
  key3: value3,
  _index: [
    'key1', 'key2', 'key3'
  ]
};
```

And, I'd recommend either using [sort and a compare function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) or [splicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to manage the index.